# Auto Arranging the elements using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, css-float

I have an application in which I am kind of stuck. 
i have created a widget which needs to be placed in such a way that it needs to auto place itself. 
Eg:[image]

I have something like this on a page, now initially all these are arranged perfectly(horizontally aligned), but as soon as the size of one of the component changes 
Eg:[image]

It becomes like this. What I want is it auto adjust itself to consume the empty spaces.

I played around with the css to make it float :left and display: block, by which I am able to align each component horizontally, but still I am not able to utilize the space on my page.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: just use twitter bootstrap css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a CSS only solution:

taken you want to have 3 "connection" items per row this should be your CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 1em;
}
.itm{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    border-top:1px solid red;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
    margin-bottom:1em;
}
.itm:nth-child(3n+1){
    clear:left;
}
```

and this your HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="itm">
        <h1>connections a</h1>
        <div class="info">
            <span class="label">server</span>
            <span class="value">100</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    [... copy paste as many "itm"s as you need]
</div>
```

See here a fiddle with "add more items on click" to see the result  -- old -- http://jsfiddle.net/5FsLm/ -- old --

UPDATED fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/c2nkn/

Comment: this still gives me the same thing. I mean, it doesnt utilize the blank space

Comment: misunderstanding - I thought you would have aimed for a clear alignment .. then one of the many masonry plugins is your way to go .. if you google for "CSS masonry" you find http://sickdesigner.com/masonry-css-getting-awesome-with-css3/

Comment: I updated my example inspired by sickdesigners tutorial -- plz review the new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/c2nkn/

Comment: glad I was able to help. but as also stated on sickdesigners blog this needs a fallback for <IE 9

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a perfect case for [jQuery Masonry](http://osvaldas.info/responsive-jquery-masonry-or-pinterest-style-layout). The plugin can automatically arrange columns so they can fit together. Something like this:

**html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="list">
        <div class="item"> ... </div>
        <div class="item"> ... </div>
        <div class="item"> ... </div>
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#list').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.item'
    });
});
```

P.S.: At the moment, the official website is down for some reason, I will put a temporary link here.

---

UPDATE: [Temporary link for jQuery Masonry](http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/themes/cutestpaw2/js/masonry/js/jquery.masonry.min.js) (actually from cutestpaw.com which has a local copy of it, so if you want to test it, you should copy the file instead of linking to it)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, it looks like what you really want is a three column structure for these widgets. In which case it would look something like this.

### HTML

```
<div class='three-column'>
    <div class="widget">...</div>
    <div class="widget">...</div>
    <div class="widget">...</div>
</div>
<div class='three-column'>
...
</div>
<div class='three-column'>
...
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.three-column {
    width: 30%;
    padding-right: 3%;
    float: left;
}
```

UPDATED: http://jsfiddle.net/cBgj4

Comment: So my structure is soemthing like this <div class="blockFloat component_main" style="margin-bottom: 5px; margin-right: 28px;">
<div class="outer_stats">Connections</div>
        <div class="stats_data"><div class="inner_stats" style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><div class="label_stats">server</div>
<div class="data_stats"><span>100</span></div>


</div></div>
        <div class="lower_stats"></div></div>

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want much animations and need a script that very easy to understand and satisfies your purpose try jquery.popbild.js.

You can download the project from :http://funscripts.popbild.com/jquery_popbild/

Its mainly created to arrange element in the pinterest style for three columns(uses three divisions)